# Ошибка компиляции программы swift

Tags: swift

Имеется такой код и ошибка: Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'executer'. Я хотел бы в колбэке который передается scheduledTimer вызвать функцию executer. Как это сделать и в чем моя ошибка?

```
func executeThrough(timeInterval ti: TimeInterval, executer: () -> Void) -> () -> Void {

  var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: ti, repeats: false) { _ in
      executer()
  }

  func cancelExecute() -> Void {
      timer.invalidate()
  }

  return cancelExecute
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В том и ошибка, что executer non-escaping. Нужно добавить ему @escaping чтобы перестало ругаться.
Вот так:

‘executer: @escaping () -> Void’